# How do I identify which controller is which DirectInput device?

Tags: controllers

I have a large number of different types of game controllers hooked up by USB to my PC, which is powering a MAME/arcade cabinet.

Problem I'm having is that whenever I go to define my controls in certain games, they always get overridden by "joy2_dig0_up". Similarly in other games, the cursor just keeps moving upward, or the character just keeps moving upward. In other words, one of my controllers is grabbing control of the game and pushing up constantly.

How do I determine WHICH of my various bits of plastic corresponds to "joy2" so I can eliminate it? And for that matter... once I figure out which device it is, is there a way to block it for the games that it interferes with other than unplugging the thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Device Manager (I assume you are running Windows since you said 'PC').

In device manager find USB/Game Controller, it could be either/or and in your case there may be multiple duplicates/similar choices, and click on properties.

You should see a window that lets you 'test input' and shows some monitors for different input types. Granted that all the pieces between software are aligned correctly, you should see the 'forward/up' input being triggered on the joystick/controller that is responsible:

[image: joystick properties showing input testing]

If you got this far, you can simply disable the device in Device Manager to stop it. You would have to enable it again when you want to use it though, I don't know of any software that would allow per program disabling/enabling.

Comment: Bingo! I found which was the culprit -- my VJoy virtual joystick device driver. Wasn't even any of my plastic controllers at all.

Comment: @StefanGagne happy to help